# CSS sidebar with fixed width and fluid content

Tags: html, css, width, fixed, fluid

I'm trying to add a sidebar with a fixed width. But the content div should be fluid.

Here is my code:

```css
.page-main{
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page-content{
    background-color: red;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page-side {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-main">
                <div class="page-content">
                    Content

                </div>
                <div class="page-side">
                    Sidebar
                </div>
            </div>
```

I hope someone can help.

Comment: so whats your actual problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just move `.page-side` before `.page-content` in your html

```css
.page-main{
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page-content{
    background-color: red;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page-side {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-main">
  <div class="page-side">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="page-content">
    Content
  </div>                
</div>
```

Comment: @R3Tech good practise to keep floated elements on top: http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101#section2

Comment: I put the content first in the HTML whenever possible. The sidebar stuff is usually not that important, so putting it at the end tends to make responsive layouts easier. IMHO...

Answer (score 3):

1.you can use css expression

`.page-content {width: calc(100% - 200px);float:left}`

2.or you can set the sidebar to absolute,and add margin-right for page-content

```
.page-side {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 18px;
}
.page-content {
    background-color: red;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure whether you want to your sidebar width to exact 200px you can assign width in percentage too... i hope this helps

```
<div class="page-main">

            <div class="page-content">
                Content

            </div>

            <div class="page-side">
                Sidebar
            </div>
        </div>

.page-main{
padding: 10px;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
.page-content{
background-color: red;
width: auto;
overflow: hidden;
float:left;
width: 61%;
}

.page-side {
float: right;
width: 200px;
background-color: green;
}
```

OR check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/pjx6wqrw/3/

{edited to remove jsfiddle link from the code block}

Comment: works well if you will never have page content shorter than runner

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative margin.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="content">
    </div><!-- .content -->

    <div class="sidebar">
    </div><!-- .sidebar -->

</div><!-- .wrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    margin-right: 300px;
}
.content{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar{
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 300px;
}
```

full explanation and example for 2-3 columns layout:

https://shellcreeper.com/responsive-fixed-width-sidebar-why-and-how/